How the message is output to the client in the chat server example from the Go programming language book?
Below is an example of a chat server from Chapter 8 of Alan Donovan and Brian Kernighan's book Go Programming Language.
// Chat is a server that lets clients chat with each other.
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

//!+broadcaster
type client chan<- string // an outgoing message channel

var (
    entering = make(chan client)
    leaving  = make(chan client)
    messages = make(chan string) // all incoming client messages
)

func broadcaster() {
    clients := make(map[client]bool) // all connected clients
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-messages:
            // Broadcast incoming message to all
            // clients' outgoing message channels.
            for cli := range clients {
                fmt.Println(cli)
                cli <- msg
            }

        case cli := <-entering:
            clients[cli] = true

        case cli := <-leaving:
            delete(clients, cli)
            close(cli)
        }
    }
}

//!-broadcaster

//!+handleConn
func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    ch := make(chan string) // outgoing client messages
    go clientWriter(conn, ch)

    who := conn.RemoteAddr().String()
    ch <- "You are " + who
    messages <- who + " has arrived"
    entering <- ch

    input := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
    for input.Scan() {
        messages <- who + ": " + input.Text()
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()

    leaving <- ch
    messages <- who + " has left"
    conn.Close()
}

func clientWriter(conn net.Conn, ch <-chan string) {
    for msg := range ch {
        fmt.Fprintln(conn, msg) // NOTE: ignoring network errors
    }
}

//!-handleConn

//!+main
func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go broadcaster()
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            continue
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
    }
}

//!-main


One point is not obvious to me at all. In the broacaster function we have map clients, where the key is the outgoing message channel for each client. Sending a message to the chat room:
for cli := range clients {
    fmt.Println(cli)
    cli <- msg
}

we send a string to this outgoing message channel.
Where does the message output from this outgoing message channel take place? Where is this channel read and output?
In the clientWriter function only some ch := make(chan string) is passed, but as I see it has nothing to do with the outgoing message channel.
I want to get an understanding of how the message is passed to the terminal output.

The first line of the handleConn function creates the outgoing message channel for the client.  The second line of handleConn starts a goroutine to receive values from the outgoing message channel and write to the connection.

There is no “terminal output”.
In main you have
        conn, ... := listener.Accept()
        ...
        go handleConn(conn)

so every connected client (i.e. with netcat) is handeled in its own goroutine handleConn.
